Auto-indentation does not work properly with curly brackets when they are preceded by a pipe operator in RStudio
Indent the following lines of code with the key shortcuts
CTRL + A followed by CTRL + I
mtcars |> 
  identity()

{
  t <- 1
}
# Do CTRL + A and CTRL + I

The results is not pretty :
mtcars |> 
  identity()

{
  t <- 1
  } # this curly bracket is not aligned

It does work when the function is in the same ligne as the pipe operator.
